# How to get out of stuck boot animation?(Android One)

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode

I am stuck at the google boot animation of the android one phone(Micromax AQ501). I had just flashed it into custom recovery for the first time. It rebooted for the first time after that and then got stuck. It shows its OEM unlocked. I tried to boot into the recovery mode but it gets switched off on its own. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to flash the Factory Image now using SP Flash tool. I have provided a link below, but confirm it's for AQ501. Alternatively, you can also try flashing the stock recovery.img for your phone.

Warning - You might lose data!

Source - http://forum.xda-developers.com/canvas-a1/development/official-stock-rom-canvas-a1-t2887150